# redirigir de http con y sin www a https

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

buen día, estoy tratando como menciono en el titulo pero no lo logro, lo que quiero es pasar de http ya sea (con y sin www ) y https://www a --> https://example.com como podría mediante mediante htaccess

esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora y funciona pero solo sin el www 
pdt: también quiero redirigir index.php https://expalme.com

```
# reglas ocultar index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: lo ideal es que hicieras un virtualhost:80 y un virtualhost:443 en el 80 redireccionas y en el 443 funciona normal, trabajarlo en el .htaccess , no soy muy fanatico a esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hola Christopher es super importante revises [answer] para que en base a lo comentado ahí realices tus respuestas, en este caso agrega una explicación del código para que sea de utilidad tu respuesta a la comunidad, saludos!

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys no tengo nada que explicar la verdad, que les haya servido es lo importante.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi configuración para el archivo donde segun lo que he leido es la correcta para un mejor SEO, ya que por experiencia cada persona tiene una manera distinta de acceder a una web.
Puedes probar tu configuracion en este enlace: https://httpstatus.io

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.jaimefranko.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://jaimefranko.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```